# Create widget with transparent hole inside

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

How can I create a semi-transparent background with the transparent hole inside? I tried to use decoration and foreground decorations with different blend modes, stack, ClipRect, colorfilters, but nothing works. I will appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

[image: Semi-transparent background with transparent hole inside]

Comment: Will be useful for you 
https://dev.to/flutterclutter/flutter-how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-overlay-a0

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The "easiest" way I've found to do it is using a **ColorFiltered Widget** with a **Stack**.

The following code will create exactly what you need:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Material(
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Image.network(
        'https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/e/5/3/13586.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.srcOut), // This one will create the magic
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.dstOut), // This one will handle background + difference out
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Hello World',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 70, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

This one you not only create "holes" over views, it works with anything! including texts, etc.

Final result:

[image: Mask Out]

Comment: You are a miracle worker. Thanks! This was a lifesaver for keeping an element visible beneath an overlay.

Comment: Is it possible to make black background with blur?

Comment: @ArturDumchev Did you find a solution for combining opacity and blur?

Comment: Just wrap the `Image.network` with `ImageFiltered` widget and set it's `imageFilter` property. `imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),`