# How to stop ColorFiltered blending?

Tags: flutter

I followed the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357361/create-widget-with-transparent-hole-inside) to create a widget with a transparent hole. My problem now is that any other widgets I place on the screen have a blend effect as well. I would
like this to not be the case, if possible. Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            'https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/8/3/a/35405.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          ColorFiltered(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                BlendMode.srcOut), // This one will create the magic
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode
                                .dstOut), // This one will handle background + difference out
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                          height: 200,
                          width: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Text("Test",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 64,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

I want the text widget "Test" to be in red and not show the image below. **Any widget** placed above the color filter should not be blended with the background. I've tried wrapping the text in a ColorFiltered widget and setting the BlendMode to "src" which should discard the destination image (if I understand the documentation correctly), but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using a stack, just pull out the text wsidget from the ColoredFilter widget and place it after the widget. This way it will appear on top.

something like this (not tested):

```
Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            'https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/8/3/a/35405.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          ColorFiltered(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                BlendMode.srcOut), // This one will create the magic
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode
                                .dstOut), // This one will handle background + difference out
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                          height: 200,
                          width: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),

// I just moved text widget here, you may need to apply any Position, align, padding, margin you wish, since it is now outside of the Expand widget
            Text("Test",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 64,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Hey thanks this worked. It's funny, this is actually the first thing I tried, but unlike the sample code I gave, I didn't make the text big. So I never noticed it all the way at the top left of the screen. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped