# How to make a widget inside a widget transparent so that the third widget is visible

Tags: flutter

I want the first widget to be transparent and display the colors of the third widget. on the third widget there is an animation with changing colors

[image]

Comment: SOLUTION https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357361/create-widget-with-transparent-hole-inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ColorFiltered` for that.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Material(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // make sure the filter is restricted
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.black, // Color of the box, must be same color as text color used below
            BlendMode.xor,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'test',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                color: Colors.black, // Same color as filter color used above
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

The `BlendMode.xor` will cut out everything with the same color within the current canvas, which is the `Material` widget above it.

Comment: How do I do this if I want to put it in a Card?

Answer (score 0):

Try the opacity widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.5,
  child: ...,
)
```

Comment: if i make 1. widget just transparent then it will be just black. i want to get 3. widget colors

Comment: To be honest it would be easier if you give us your code so we can test the changes. If I understand right you want only the text to be transparent?

Comment: Also can try to give the color of your first widget like this: `color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)`

Comment: Text should be same color as background. but i cant make it transparent ( opacity()) cuz then it will be black