# Clip inside of a ClipPath in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to reverse/flip what is clipped in a ClipPath? Instead of clipping the outside of the path, it'll clip the inside.

What is happening right now when clipping:

[image]

What i want to to happen when clipping:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate the label area of the TextFormField where it's sitting over the border's outline and also hides the line under the label.

Comment: can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Hey @YeasinSheikh, this isn't an error. Sorry for wording it like it's an error. From what i understand Clipping will only show what's inside the clipped area and hide the outside. I'm looking for a way to hide the inside of the clipped area and show the outside area.

Comment: you can define the clipPath based on your need, it can create hole inside in it

Comment: I think i've got it. Were you talking about changing the fill type to evenodd?

Comment: yap, you can do that way , rect+circle. you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071056/10157127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this pattern

```dart
class HoleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  const HoleClipper({
    this.holeRadiusRatio = 0.5,
  });

  final double holeRadiusRatio;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    path.addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

    final holeSize = min(size.width, size.height) * holeRadiusRatio;
    path.addOval(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
        width: holeSize,
        height: holeSize,
      ),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant HoleClipper oldClipper) =>
      oldClipper.holeRadiusRatio != holeRadiusRatio;
}
```

And use like

```dart
class TestWidG extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidG({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: HoleClipper(holeRadiusRatio: 0.7),
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result

[image]