# Page transition with circle in the center that expands revealing the second view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, page-transition

I am trying to do a Page transition using a circle in the center of the first view that expands revealing second view.

In alternative, it's the same if I use a widget with a transparent hole in the center (and we can see the bottom widget through the hole), and with an animation that expands the hole revealing the widget in the bottom.

The only answer I found similar to what I'm trying to do is this:

[How to create widget with transparent hole in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068502/how-to-create-widget-with-transparent-hole-in-flutter)

but I am not able to use a widget instead of the circle ping the center of the screen.

Comment: You need to extend  `PageRouteBuilder` and return  `ShaderMask`  from buildTransitions.

Comment: You can check [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/custom_page_route.git) I used for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `HoleMaterialPageRoute` instead of `MaterialPageRoute` - note that you can completely remove `transitionDuration` if the default duration is ok with you, also you can remove `late final curve = CurvedAnimation(` and use `animation.value` instead of `curve.value` but in my opinion non linear radius growth looks better :-)

```
class HoleMaterialPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  HoleMaterialPageRoute({required super.builder});

  // the default transitionDuration is Duration(milliseconds: 300) so you can make
  // it longer to see the better effect:
  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 800);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: _HoleClipper(animation),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class _HoleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  _HoleClipper(this.animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  late final curve = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animation,
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
    reverseCurve: Curves.easeIn,
  );

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final center = size.center(Offset.zero);
    final radius = lerpDouble(0, center.distance, curve.value)!;
    // print('size: $size, radius: $radius');
    final oval = Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius);
    return Path()
      ..addOval(oval);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

**EDIT**

in some cases a better solution is to use `ThemeData.pageTransitionsTheme` so that you can use `Navigator.pushNamed` or `Navigator.push` with "normal" `MaterialPageRoute` (you dont have to change your `Navigator` related code)

to do so you have to create a custom `PageTransitionsBuilder`:

```
class HolePageTransitionsBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(PageRoute<T> route, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: _HoleClipper(animation),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like that (this is a case for linux platform where i tested my code):

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light(useMaterial3: false).copyWith(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.linux: HolePageTransitionsBuilder(),
      }
    )
  ),
  ...
)
```